# Stripe Integration Testing on Localhost for Automated Account-Creation System

Tags: php, stripe-payments, e-commerce, webhooks

I've been tasked with creating a Stripe Integration solution that involves taking certain information from a donation through Stripe and account for all events needed to be able to create an account if their donation completes successfully, or contact the user and explain why their donation failed. Here are the requirements:

- If the immediate donation succeeds, take their email, name, and amount donated and create an account for them on our website.
- If the donation is async and succeeds, do the same as above.
- If the donation is async and fails, send an email to the user with the details of the donation failure.

We aren't taking any kind of financial information or any other PII than what is necessary for the listed requirements. Here are the events I know our webhook needs to listen for:

- `payment_intent.succeeded`
- `checkout.session.completed`
- `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded`
- `checkout.session.async_payment_failed`

Fairly simple; however, there is a huge amount of information in their docs, and the vast majority of it is useless for a system like this. On top of that, my company just set up a new dev environment that I am required to use in order to develop this system. Unfortunately, it's not set up very well because none of us out here are professional sysadmins.

So far, I have created the webhook, the payment link (Buy Now button), and set up the CLI on the dev machine as best as I knew how (which admittedly isn't all that well, but I followed Stripe's tutorials for everything in this whole situation). But I know that it at least partially works. I only know it works, though, because I fudged a bit after getting frustrated for a week trying to get the CLI to trigger events to no avail. I created a quick test page in a secluded part of our live server (I know, I'm a rebel, but I do have a cause!) just testing to make sure there weren't any PHP errors on my part, and the webhook worked perfectly. I even saw some responses on the dev machine while testing the webhook on the live site as well as leaving the dev machine listening on its own webhook. So the live site's webhook forwarded to the dev machine's webhook. But when it came to solely the webhook on the dev machine, no triggered events get any kind of response.

On the dev machine, I log in and start listening doing exactly what the tutorial says:

```
stripe login -i
<I put in the api key>
stripe listen --skip-verify --forward-to http://localhost:42424/path/to/webhook.php
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

I never get any response or anything that shows that the event was successfully triggered. I have talked to Stripe's support, but they have been no help thus far. The only time I've gotten a response was, as I stated above, when I tested the live site's webhook, and it also forwarded to the localhost. Those responses looked like this:

```
2023-10-25 13:28:11   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_...]
2023-10-25 13:28:11            [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:42424/path/to/webhook.php": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:42424: connect: connection refused
```

So I really just have a couple questions I need help with in this situation from anyone who is knowledgeable of such things:

- Do I need to listen for any more events than the ones mentioned above?
- Can anyone help me with, or at least point me in a decent direction as to, the reason why my Stripe CLI isn't working correctly?

Comment: It might help getting an answer if you remove a lot of the context about your job and circumstances. Not that it's irrelevant in your situation, but it makes your question to bloated.

Comment: @NigelRen Noted and done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to listen for any more events than the ones mentioned above?

You shouldn't need to, no.

> Can anyone help me with, or at least point me in a decent direction as to, the reason why my Stripe CLI isn't working correctly?

Do you have a server running on port `42424` for your webhook handler at the `http://localhost:42424/path/to/webhook.php` address? Not sure if it's intentional or not, but you have `42424` instead of `4242`. Is your CLI listener still running?

If so, I would do a dump of your network logs to see why the connection was refused. Stripe appears to be forwarding your webhooks correctly, but for some reason your server is refusing to accept the network request.